# How to make a DM command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a command that only works if a user is DMing their command. How do I do that? I am using discord.py 1.5.1, and I'm fairly new to discord.py.
Here is my code so far:

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description='- shows this message', intents=intents)
---- snip ----

@commands.command(brief='a DM command')
async def dm_command(ctx):
    # do stuff here

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

When I try DMing the command, the bot doesn't pick up the DM I sent. Should I specify the command in on_message()?

Comment: "*Is there any way to do it?*" I'm sure there is. (Questions that are answerable with a simple "yes" or "no" are generally poor fits for Stack Overflow's Q&A format. Edit your question to share more pertinent details, including, at a minimum, what code you've put together so far in an attempt to solve the problem at hand, and a detailed explanation of where *specifically* in those attempts you're getting stuck. Stack Overflow **will not** write your code *for* you. See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code for your query:

```
@bot.command()
async def dm_command(ctx):
    if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
        #do stuff here
```

First of all, the decorator you use is not what I was taught when i first learned discord.py, so I changed the decorator from `@commands.command(brief='a DM command')` to `@bot.command()` (Feel free to change back if it works for you). Then, the rest is fairly simple. I just checked if the channel was a DM channel, and thats it! If you have any questions about my code or if you have unforseen errors, follow up!

Comment: `@commands.command()` is used if the command is inside a cog `@bot.command()` or `@client.command()` is used when its in the main file

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the pointer! I'm actually implementing (trying to implement at least) my very first cog, and this will help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx):
     await ctx.author.send('Hi im a discord bot!')#this is the message that will pop up in ur dms when u input the cmd

client.run('Token')
```